# unable to remove additional cart and checkout pages in the header of site created by wordpress with WooCommerce integration

Tags: php, wordpress, web, woocommerce

I am experienceing an issue on the header tab of a website that I have created using Wordpress with WooCommerce integration:

I am seeing additional Cart and Checkout functions tab on the header on top of the cart bag. Since I am not able to edit the header at all, I am not able to remove it from the wordpress customizer. I have checked with the woocommerce support and they have indicated that I will need to change part of the header.php file.Anyone has any idea of which part of the file needs to be changed? It definitly needs to do something with the WooCommerce codes, but I am unsure of which line to ammend safely and I do not have any experience with php files.
[This is the link to the image of the header screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoEaK.png)

```
<?php if (class_exists('WooCommerce') && get_theme_mod(CustomizerControls::NAVIGATION_HIDE_CART) == '') : ?>
                                    <div class="cart-header cart-header-desktop">
                                        <a class="cart-customlocation" href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr('View your shopping cart'); ?>">
                                            <svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M21.9353 20.0337L20.7493 8.51772C20.7003 8.0402 20.2981 7.67725 19.8181 7.67725H4.21338C3.73464 7.67725 3.33264 8.03898 3.28239 8.51523L2.06458 20.0368C1.96408 21.0424 2.29928 22.0529 2.98399 22.8097C3.66874 23.566 4.63999 24.0001 5.64897 24.0001H18.3827C19.387 24.0001 20.3492 23.5747 21.0214 22.8322C21.7031 22.081 22.0361 21.0623 21.9353 20.0337ZM19.6348 21.5748C19.3115 21.9312 18.8668 22.1275 18.3827 22.1275H5.6493C5.16836 22.1275 4.70303 21.9181 4.37252 21.553C4.042 21.1878 3.88005 20.7031 3.92749 20.2284L5.056 9.55014H18.9732L20.0724 20.2216C20.1223 20.7281 19.9666 21.2087 19.6348 21.5748Z" fill="currentColor"></path> <path d="M12.1717 0C9.21181 0 6.80365 2.40811 6.80365 5.36803V8.6138H8.67622V5.36803C8.67622 3.44053 10.2442 1.87256 12.1717 1.87256C14.0992 1.87256 15.6674 3.44053 15.6674 5.36803V8.6138H17.5397V5.36803C17.5397 2.40811 15.1316 0 12.1717 0Z" fill="currentColor"></path> </svg>
                                            <span class="cart-icon-number"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span> 

                                            <div class="cart-preview">
                                                <?php
            global $woocommerce;
                                    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

                                    foreach ($items as $item => $values) {
                                        $_product =  wc_get_product($values['data']->get_id());
                                        echo "<div class='cart-preview-tem'>";
                                        $getProductDetail = wc_get_product($values['product_id']);
                                        echo "<div class='thumb-container'>";
                                        echo $getProductDetail->get_image('thumb');
                                        echo "</div>";
                                        echo "".$values['quantity']. ' x '.$_product->get_title();
                                        $price = $values['data']->get_price();
                                        echo "<span>";
                                        echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                                        echo "".esc_html($price)."</span></div>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (class_exists('WooCommerce') && get_theme_mod(CustomizerControls::NAVIGATION_HIDE_CART) == '') : ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```

Will be really grateful for any help regarding this matter!

I have tried to disable the plugins in wordpress and slowly enabling one by one but the issue seems to persist. The issue seems to be there from the start when I integrated WooCommerce into my online store.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there should be a setting in the Dashboard for your theme that allows you to hide the cart from the navigation, but if you can't find it, you could replace the code above with what I put here, which will disable the feature completely.

```
<?php if (false && class_exists('WooCommerce') && get_theme_mod(CustomizerControls::NAVIGATION_HIDE_CART) == '') : ?>
                                    <div class="cart-header cart-header-desktop">
                                        <a class="cart-customlocation" href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr('View your shopping cart'); ?>">
                                            <svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M21.9353 20.0337L20.7493 8.51772C20.7003 8.0402 20.2981 7.67725 19.8181 7.67725H4.21338C3.73464 7.67725 3.33264 8.03898 3.28239 8.51523L2.06458 20.0368C1.96408 21.0424 2.29928 22.0529 2.98399 22.8097C3.66874 23.566 4.63999 24.0001 5.64897 24.0001H18.3827C19.387 24.0001 20.3492 23.5747 21.0214 22.8322C21.7031 22.081 22.0361 21.0623 21.9353 20.0337ZM19.6348 21.5748C19.3115 21.9312 18.8668 22.1275 18.3827 22.1275H5.6493C5.16836 22.1275 4.70303 21.9181 4.37252 21.553C4.042 21.1878 3.88005 20.7031 3.92749 20.2284L5.056 9.55014H18.9732L20.0724 20.2216C20.1223 20.7281 19.9666 21.2087 19.6348 21.5748Z" fill="currentColor"></path> <path d="M12.1717 0C9.21181 0 6.80365 2.40811 6.80365 5.36803V8.6138H8.67622V5.36803C8.67622 3.44053 10.2442 1.87256 12.1717 1.87256C14.0992 1.87256 15.6674 3.44053 15.6674 5.36803V8.6138H17.5397V5.36803C17.5397 2.40811 15.1316 0 12.1717 0Z" fill="currentColor"></path> </svg>
                                            <span class="cart-icon-number"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span> 

                                            <div class="cart-preview">
                                                <?php
            global $woocommerce;
                                    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

                                    foreach ($items as $item => $values) {
                                        $_product =  wc_get_product($values['data']->get_id());
                                        echo "<div class='cart-preview-tem'>";
                                        $getProductDetail = wc_get_product($values['product_id']);
                                        echo "<div class='thumb-container'>";
                                        echo $getProductDetail->get_image('thumb');
                                        echo "</div>";
                                        echo "".$values['quantity']. ' x '.$_product->get_title();
                                        $price = $values['data']->get_price();
                                        echo "<span>";
                                        echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                                        echo "".esc_html($price)."</span></div>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (false && class_exists('WooCommerce') && get_theme_mod(CustomizerControls::NAVIGATION_HIDE_CART) == '') : ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```